# how to skip public folder name in derive file path from db laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, laravel-5.4, public

Controller store function code

```
 $file = $request->file('photo');
        $name =$fileid.'.'.date('Y-m H:s').'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();

        $Photo=$request->photo->storeAs('public/uploads',$name);
        $add->Photo=$Photo;
        $add->save();
```

controller show function

```
$output .= '<img src="storage/'.$key->Photo.'" alt="" class="img-responsive">';
```

in here $key->Photo return (public/uploads/14.2018-06%2012:56.jpg)

> http://localhost:8000/storage/public/uploads/14.2018-06%2012:56.jpg

This url not found 
but

> http://localhost:8000/storage/uploads/14.2018-06%2012:56.jpg

just remove public word in url it's working 
This url to show photo

how to solve this issue please help me to sort out this

note :- I linked storage folder by php artisan storage:link commend

Answer (score 0):

just add this code into your controller

```
$file = $request->file('photo');
    $name =$fileid.'.'.date('Y-m H:s').'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();

    $Photo=$request->photo->storeAs('public/uploads',$name);
    $Photo1=('/uploads',$name);
    $add->Photo=$Photo1;
    $add->save();
```

I think Your problem solved by this code but i have no idea about skip public folder